# Serialization perfomance in Android

Tags: java, android

I try to compare Serializable vs Externalizable vs Parcelable. Is Externalizable faster than Serializable in Android?

I expected that Externalizable much faster than Serializable but in real case I see absolutely the same result.

Idea of my test: create a lot of activities and use method Bundle getSerializable for getting list of Serializables or Externalizables objects. And compare perfomance.

Result of my test:

1) 
Externalizable : 3462 ms
Serializable: 3762 ms
Parceble : 300 ms

2) 
Externalizable : 3780 ms
Serializable: 3853 ms
Parceble : 329 ms

3)

Externalizable : 3533 ms
Serializable: 4063 ms
Parceble : 339 ms

code here: https://github.com/mlevytskiy/SerializableVsParcebleVsExternalizable

```
package serializable.petproject.serializablevsparceblevsexternalizable;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MySerializableClass implements Serializable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1865151003590118998L;
    public String mStringData = "";
    public int mIdenty = 0;
    public boolean mIsActive = false;
    public float mDest = 0.0f;
    public ArrayList<String> mStringList;

    public MySerializableClass() {
        mStringData = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        mStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int maxI = rand.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxI % 15; i++) 
        {
            mStringList.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        mIdenty = rand.nextInt();
        mIsActive = rand.nextBoolean();
        mDest = rand.nextFloat();
    }
}
```

Externalizable:

```
    package serializable.petproject.serializablevsparceblevsexternalizable;

import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by max on 12/12/18.
 */

public class MyExternalizbleClass implements Externalizable {

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1865151003590118998L;
    public String mStringData = "";
    public int mIdenty = 0;
    public boolean mIsActive = false;
    public float mDest = 0.0f;
    public ArrayList<String> mStringList;

    public MyExternalizbleClass() {
        mStringData = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        mStringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int maxI = rand.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < maxI % 15; i++)
        {
            mStringList.add(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        }

        mIdenty = rand.nextInt();
        mIsActive = rand.nextBoolean();
        mDest = rand.nextFloat();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(mStringData);
        out.writeInt(mIdenty);
        out.writeBoolean(mIsActive);
        out.writeFloat(mDest);
        out.writeObject(mStringList);

    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal(ObjectInput input) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        mStringData = input.readUTF();
        mIdenty = input.readInt();
        mIsActive = input.readBoolean();
        mDest = input.readFloat();
        mStringList = (ArrayList<String>) input.readObject();
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by max on 12/14/18.
 */

public class ExternalizableActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PARCELABLE_ARRAY = "parcelable_array";

    public ArrayList<MyExternalizbleClass> items;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Date time = new Date();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            items = (ArrayList<MyExternalizbleClass>) extras.getSerializable(PARCELABLE_ARRAY);
        }
        Date now = new Date();
        long delta = now.getTime() - time.getTime();

        if (App.attendCount == 0) {
            Log.w("MainActivity", "Summary externalizable time: " + App.allTime + " ms.");
            //clear
            App.allTime = -1;
            App.attendCount = App.ITEMS_COUNT;
            return;
        }

        if (App.attendCount > 0) {
            App.allTime = App.allTime + delta;
            App.attendCount = App.attendCount - 1;
            startTest();
        }
    }

    public void startTest() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < App.ITEMS_COUNT; i++) {
            items.add(new MyExternalizbleClass());
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ExternalizableActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(PARCELABLE_ARRAY, items);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Comment: Running your code in my emulator I have that Serializable is even faster than Externalizable. As other answers to the difference of the two methods say, I think that there is no reason in using Externalizable unless you need to have control in what and how data is written to the output stream. For sure I think you have already proved that there is no performance gain.

Comment: Unfortunately I found a library
https://github.com/twitter/serial
which to do what have to do Externilizable.
In case when we want to use serialization to pack object into persistence storage, not only in Bundle we can't use Parcelable. 
Parcel is not a general-purpose serialization mechanism